# Does method reference get rid of overridable method calls?

Tags: java, constructor, lambda, overriding, java-8

I was writing the following code, and I noticed a difference in warning messages:

```
public abstract class Yielder<E> implements Iterator<E> {
    private final Object lock = new Object();

    private final Thread yieldThread;

    private E element;

    public Yielder() {
        this.yieldThread = new Thread(this::getYields);
        startThreads();
    }

    private void startThreads() {
        yieldThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        //impl
    }

    @Override
    public E next() {
        //impl
    }

    protected void yield(final E yield) {
        //impl
    }

    abstract protected void getYields();
}
```

---

```
public class IncrementingYielder extends Yielder<Integer> {
    @Override
    protected void getYields() {
        int i = 0;
        while (true) {
            yield(i++);
        }
    }
}
```

When in the constructor of `Yielder<E>`, if I write:

- `this.yieldThread = new Thread(() -> getYields())`, I get as warning `Overridable method call in constructor`.
- `this.yieldThread = new Thread(this::getYields)`, then everything is fine.

Is there really a difference here? Or is the Netbeans 8.0 Beta not configured to warn for method references yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no difference in these two usages. Especially in this case you can derive the answer from the fact that the referenced method is `abstract`. Any code calling this method *must* end up in an overridden method.

In this special case the IDE should warn you in both cases— not because you are calling the overridable method in the constructor but because the `this` instance escapes from the constructor.

It doesn’t matter which construct you use, lambda or method reference, the code is not thread safe. You are even risking that your started threads break because they might see `null` values for your lock object.

To put it in one line, never start threads from within a constructor.